# Read and write days of the week high and low temp and daily average to/from file

Tags: java

I need to read from a file the day of the week and a temperature. My program needs to write out to a file the day of the week, high temp, low temp and the daily average. I need to use arrays. Here's my code:

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.util.Formatter; 
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class dowwithfiles 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("Dowinputnumbers.txt")); 
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter(new File("Dowoutputnumbers.txt"));
        while(scanner.hasNext())
        {

            int dow  = scanner.nextInt();
            int temp = scanner.nextInt();

            int [] dows;
            dows = new int[8];

            int [] hightemps;
            hightemps = new int[8];

            int [] lowtemps;
            lowtemps = new int[8];

            formatter.format("%d %d\n",dow, temp, dows, hightemps, lowtemps);
            {
             if(dow == 1);

                dow = dows[1];
                temp = hightemps[1];
                temp = lowtemps[1];
             if(lowtemps[1] > hightemps[1])
                lowtemps[1] = hightemps[1];
             else 
                hightemps[1] = lowtemps[1]; 

             if(dow == 2);

                dow = dows[2];
                temp = hightemps[2];
                temp = lowtemps[2];
             if(lowtemps[2] > hightemps[2])
                lowtemps[2] = hightemps[2];
             else 
                hightemps[2] = lowtemps[2]; 

             if(dow == 3);

                dow = dows[3];
                temp = hightemps[3];
                temp = lowtemps[3];
             if(lowtemps[3] > hightemps[3])
                lowtemps[3] = hightemps[3];
             else 
                hightemps[3] = lowtemps[3];     

             if(dow == 4);

                dow = dows[4];
                temp = hightemps[4];
                temp = lowtemps[4];
             if(lowtemps[4] > hightemps[4])
                lowtemps[4] = hightemps[4];
             else 
                hightemps[4] = lowtemps[4]; 

             if(dow == 5);

                dow = dows[5];
                temp = hightemps[5];
                temp = lowtemps[5];
             if(lowtemps[5] > hightemps[5])
                lowtemps[5] = hightemps[5];
             else 
                hightemps[5] = lowtemps[5]; 

             if(dow == 6);

                dow = dows[6];
                temp = hightemps[6];
                temp = lowtemps[6];
             if(lowtemps[6] > hightemps[6])
                lowtemps[6] = hightemps[6];
             else 
                hightemps[6] = lowtemps[6]; 

             if(dow == 7);

                dow = dows[7];
                temp = hightemps[7];
                temp = lowtemps[7];
             if(lowtemps[7] > hightemps[7])
                lowtemps[7] = hightemps[7];
             else 
                hightemps[7] = lowtemps[7];   
            break;

            }

          }
    // flush the buffer to disk (makes sure everything gets
    // written out to the file)
        formatter.flush();
        formatter.close();
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
     double[] highTemps;
        highTemps = new double[7];
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     int dow = scanner.nextInt();
     highTemps[dow - 1] = scanner.nextDouble();
     {

     }

    }
   }
   }
```

Comment: Can you post your file?

Comment: What is the question? Is there a problem with the program? Are you getting errors?

Comment: i just randomly picked numbers 1-7 mon = 1 tues = 2 and so on
7     97
4     75
3     66
3     76 
1     23
2     87  in two vertical columns 

I'm just getting confused with the arrays.. now my output is not writing to the file. and I'm lost in the program